# Render scene at lower resolution (three.js)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

How can i decrease my rendered canvas resolution(just like i can do on blender camera resolution)? I've seen another question saying that i need to use

```
renderer.setDevicePixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
```

The problem is that the object either gets black or nothing shows on canvas, so i don't really know if this is it solves my problem.

I also tried to use

```
renderer.setSize()
```

and

```
renderer.setViewport()
```

together and separately, but it only changed the canvas size to a very small one(i need a high size preview of the canvas), and even though the viewport got on the size i wanted, it seems that the objects are rendered only on the smaller size, so i can't see all of it, so it doesn't do the trick.

Also, if possible, is there a way to do that by manually changing the image buffer to a lower resolution one, and displaying it?

Answer (score 1):

The thing i needed was the setPixelRatio function on therenderer. no setDevicePixelRatio.